# Неполучение репутации за принятые правки как на en-SO - баг или фича?

Tags: поддержка, репутация, привилегии

**Дано:**

1. Идём на `en-SO`
2. Берём любой вопрос с кол-вом меток < 5.
3. Добавляем полезную метку.
4. Вопрос попадает в очередь и через `n` минут правка принята.
5. За принятую правку в репу летит `+2`.

Если же повторить сии действия тут у нас, то `+2` в репу не прилетит.

**Вопрос:**

Это баг или фича? Связано ли это с тем, что мы в бете?

**Иначе сформулированный вопрос:**

Таки не выйдет написать бота, собирающего таким образом тут урожай? Это и ботоводу полезно и сайту, если алгоритм продумать)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

На En.SO у вас меньше 2000 репутации, [нет соответствующей привилегии](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), правки проверяются. За проверенную правку дается немного репутации. Считается, что до получения привилегии участник ещё учится, так что +2 репутации - это печенька за успешно выполненное учебное задание.

На Ru.SO у вас больше 1000 репутации (и даже больше 2000), [привилегия есть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), правки применяются напрямую. Раз вы уже научились, печеньки больше не полагаются.

Бот долго не продержится. Проверяющие очень быстро находят таких фермеров и устраивают на Мете показательную порку, за которой может следовать бан.

Comment: Ну вот( Я то обнаружил эту фичу на en-S0, когда добирал до значка "200 репы за день" и думал уже, что так же можно и золотой значок получить(

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я видел пользователя, который 4 дня подряд получал 200 почти только за правки. Нашел его как раз через вопрос на Мете ) http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295565/2790048

Comment: ну, я только полезные теги добавлял) Злоупотреблять не буду. Кстати, тут, на мете, у меня не получается после собаки увидеть всплывающее автозаполнение никнейма, как на основном сайте. Копипастить приходится. Баг?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не баг. допечатки нет, если в уже запощенных комментах нет других участников кроме вас и автора того, к чему вы пишете коммент

Comment: @ЮрийСП кстати, на правках все равно можно заработать в сумме не больше 1000 репутации (даже на enSO)

Comment: @PashaPash, да, вот теперь автодополнение заработало) Про репу понял, спасибо)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб: вот вам автозаполнение: [Есть ли кнопка «Ответить на комментарий»?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1391)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, нажал установить, словил ошибку( Буду по старинке(

Comment: @ЮрийСПб: странно. Что за ошибка?

Comment: @NickVolynkin "невозможно добавить скрипт с этого сайта". Наверняка я что-то не так делаю. Я ссылку с источника (англ) дёргал. Как применить код с ответа - я не знаю, а гуглить лень)